# Are session variables reset every time the session is destroyed?

Tags: php, html, session

I'm making a website which needs to have two types of users signing into it -
 students and admin. While the students will only have viewing rights, the admins will also be able to change things. Thus I need to have different content based on the type of user that has logged in.
So I use the following two lines of code-

```
$_SESSION['student_id'] = $row['id'];
```

and

```
$_SESSION['admin_id'] = $row['id'];
```

..to store my session variables so that I can differentiate between the type of user based on the **name of the session variable that is set**.
Something like this..

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['student_id'])) { ?>
    <h3>Success!</h3>
    <p>You have successfully registered as a student.<br>
       Your Student ID is <?php echo $_SESSION['student_id']; ?>.<br>
       Use it to log-in to your account.
    </p>
    <?php 
} else if (isset($_SESSION['admin_id'])) {
    ?>
    <h3>Success!</h3>
    <p>You have successfully registered as an administrator.<br>
       Your Admin ID is <?php echo $_SESSION['admin_id']; ?>.<br>
       Use it to log-in to your account.
    </p>
<?php } ?>
```

Is this a good way to accomplish what I want to? Are the session variables reset every time the session is destroyed, cause otherwise I don't think this is going to work.

PS: Asking this cause I'm facing problems registering admins.

Comment: If you destroy the session… then yes, the session is gone and so is all data associated with it…!?

Comment: is it possible to have both student_id and admin_id properties in session at the same time? how will your site behave then?

Comment: @IlyaBursov Nope. I've specifically written the code so that only one of them is set a time. Otherwise, the entire purpose of my code stands defeated.

Comment: @Vaibhav how do you ensure that only one of them is set?

Comment: @IlyaBursov I have a common page which contains log-in forms for both types of users. But I do have different names for the input fields. When the user clicks on the submit button for either of the forms, the data is then sent to another common page (POST method) where the following: if ($_POST['student_id'])  and else if ($_POST['admin_id']) help me determine which form was filled. I then simply set the variable at the end that is applicable.

Comment: @Vaibhav and how this ensures that only one property is set? what if I re-open this page and use another field to enter, I will be authorized twice then